# pass context to jquery hoverIntent

Tags: javascript, jquery, hoverintent

I would need to pass the context to my calls to showPictureZoom (event over).
Does anyone know how to do it? The idea is that I need to pass a variable (the image src) stored in the dom and I have no idea how I can do that...

Here is what I have so far:

```
var showPictureZoom = function(src)
{
    console.log(src)
}

var config = {
    over: function(){showPictureZoom(context)},
    sensitivity:6,
    interval:400,         
    out: hidePictureZoom,
};

$(".image img").hoverIntent(config);
```

Thanks for your help! (:

EDIT:
Here is the html code:

```
<td class="image">
    <img src="img_url" data-large-square="DATA_NEEDED">
</td>
```

What I need is to get the variable "data-large-square" in the over callback.

Comment: could you please show where and how src is being declared? or are you talking about the src attribute of some element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can pass the context to "this", that is the element:

```
var showPictureZoom = function(el)
{
    console.log($(el).attr('src'));
}

var config = {
    over: function(){showPictureZoom(this)},
    sensitivity:6,
    interval:400,         
    out: hidePictureZoom,
};

$(".image img").hoverIntent(config);
```